App stuck on white screen in Flutter, using GetX
I am working on a Flutter app, I am using GetX state management.
Whenever I run my application in debug, or release in the emulator, it works totally fine. But when I run the release on the physical device, it stuck on white screen. It works fine on first run sometimes, but after killing and opening the app again, it shows the same white screen.
Here's the code
main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/controllers/send_money_controller.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/providers/customer_provider.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/routes/route_bindings.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/util/color_util.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CustomerProvider()),
      ],
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Orbit Money',
        theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
              seedColor: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
              secondary: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
              primary: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
            ),
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
            useMaterial3: true,
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: ColorUtil.secondaryColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                errorStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ))),
        getPages: RouteBindings.routes,
        initialRoute: RouteBindings.getInitialRoute(),
        initialBinding: BindingsBuilder(() {
          Get.lazyPut(() => SendMoneyController());
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here's one of the screens:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/util/color_util.dart';
import 'package:orbit_money_app/routes/route_names.dart';

class GetStarted2View extends GetWidget {
  const GetStarted2View({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.05,
          vertical: Get.mediaQuery.size.height * 0.1),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
              'lib/assets/background_images/offwhite_circles_background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      height: Get.mediaQuery.size.height,
      width: Get.mediaQuery.size.width,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'lib/assets/logos/logo_long_black.png',
            width: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.5,
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Hello!",
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.1,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: ColorUtil.secondaryColor),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                "Welcome to Orbitmoney app, seamless experiences await at your fingertips!",
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.045,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: ColorUtil.secondaryColor),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(RouteNames.signIn);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.05,
                          vertical: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.035),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: ColorUtil.tertiaryColor,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign In",
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.05,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.03,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.toNamed(RouteNames.chooseAgent);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.15,
                          vertical: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.035),
                      backgroundColor: ColorUtil.tertiaryColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Get Started",
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: Get.mediaQuery.size.width * 0.05,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

And this is the error I am facing:


What version of getx you using? Also, are you using any library or package that is not configured or added well in the manifest file for the release build?

did you solve it? I have same error.

You need to show the debug information/ log. In order to let us know what happen after app running, I suggest you plug in your real device to your development device, and observing getx printing when you try to kill process and open it again.
Flutter debugging release mode, enable logs in release mode is the way to logging in release mode
